# Flip rows and columns in MigLayout?

Tags: java, swing, layout, miglayout

In documentation for MigLayout is written:

> Full support for left-to-right and bottom-to-top layouts.

Does this mean that i can add components not left to right in row, but in columns too? So i mean:

```
JPanel p = new JPanel(new MigLayout("flip_rows_and_columns"));
p.add(new JButton("A"));
p.add(new JButton("B"), "wrap");
p.add(new JButton("C"));
```

will produce:

```
[A][C]
[B]
```

instead of

```
[A][B]
[C]
```

For some layouts it would be probably much easier. Or can such behavior be achived somehow? May be any trick?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: flip_rows_and_columns does not really exist, it's just example

Comment: OK. The [documentation for `MigLayout`](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/miglayout/miglayout/3.7.4/miglayout-3.7.4-javadoc.jar!/net/miginfocom/swt/MigLayout.html) does not contain the word "bottom".  Link to exactly where you saw that statement.

Comment: The documentation for MigLayout does contain the word "bottom". The link is http://www.miglayout.com/QuickStart.pdf, section "Further Reading".

Comment: Of course i don't need you. My question is whether rows and columns can be flipped. Unfortunately this is not mentioned in quickstart or cheatsheet.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18089/discussion-between-avrdragon-and-andrew-thompson)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The layout constraint "flip_rows_and_columns" is "flowy" , like in:

```
MigLayout layout = new MigLayout("wrap 2, debug, flowy");
JComponent content = new JPanel(layout);
content.add(new JButton("A"));
content.add(new JButton("B"));
content.add(new JButton("C"));
```

Can be used in cells as well.